# How to use recycler view and relative layout in a screen in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and a relative layout below recycler view. My relative layout consists of three text views.My recycler view consists of three text views and a button. My problem is recycler view is scrolling separately and textviews in relative layout are fixed. But I want both to be scrolled, which means while scrolling the screen scroll should be done for both recycler view and relative layout but not seperately. While scrolling my relative layout should be attached to the end of recycler view. I have searched a lot for doing that but there is no results for my search. So, ended up here please anybody help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your RelativeLayout to scroll with the content of your RecyclerView, you'd need to add the RelativeLayout with static content to the end of the list your Adapter iterates. You'd then override [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) in the adapter and return one type ID for the data in your RecyclerView and another for the footer RelativeLayout. Then in [onCreateViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#oncreateviewholder) you'd use the view type to inflate the right kind of view (one that binds your data or another that displays your RelativeLayout).

This process can be pretty labor intensive. You might also consider using a library like [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) to help create a footer view in your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options, first one (the better one) is to create a footer ViewHolder and add it to RecyclerView as a last item in adapter.
Or you can simply wrap your views in vertical LinearLayout and then wrap it in NestedScrollView like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when you set a RecyclerView to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` the RecyclerView will no longer actually recycle its views and will instead inflate them all at once.

The NestedScrollView route is much simpler to set up if you have a small amount of data, but doesn't scale well for long lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can add view with text views in different layout and add to your recycler as last element. Then check posotion in getItemViewType and if it last return footer type inside RecyclerAdapter.

```
private static final int FOOTER = 1;
private static final int CHILD = 2;
// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == CHILD){
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    else if(viewType == FOOTER ){
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.relative, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        return FOOTER;
    } else {
        return CHILD;
    }
}
```